# Explain the logic of the correct mysqli object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So the correct format for making a query using the mysqli object is:

```
if ($result = $hookup->query($sql))
```

and not:

```
if ($result == $hookup->query($sql))
```

Why does every assume that this is the case? What is the logic behind the correct format?

Answer (score 3):

The first example (the correct one) **assigns** the result of `$hookup->query($sql)` to `$result`, which is then evaluated for "truthness" in the `if`.

The second example **compares** the *existing* value of `$result` with the result of `$hookup->query($sql)`. If `$result` is not already "truey" the `if` will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

It can be only object of `mysqli_result` return from `mysqli_query` or false if fail.

```
if (false) ... always false
if (mysqli_result) ... always true
```

However, I always do this to allow more flexibility such as stored $result for later use yet to ensure not exception

```
$result = $hookup->query($sql;
if ($result instanceof mysqli_result)
{
  /* query success, proceed with something else */ 
}
else
{
  /* query fail, execption */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two different things used in different contexts.

The first example (with one `=`) means:

> if the result of `query()` is true - oh and by the way, assign the result to the new variable `$result` - then do the following: ....

It's short-hand for assigning and checking the result in one step. In the context you show, this is usually what you want.

The second example (with two `==`) means

> if the value of `$result` equals the return value of the `query()` call, then do the following:  .....